# How to force roll over the content to next page for right side panel of page

Tags: page-breaking, page

[image]

I am using sample template of Merissa Mayer resume. How to configure right hand side page of screen shot so that the marked content should go to next page automatically.?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/recreating-business-insiders-cv-of-marissa-mayer-using-altacv/gtqfpbwncfvp
I am using above template and added more content on right had side panel so I expect it should automatically roll over to next page as left hand side page